# How many isomorphism of $\phi :\mathbb Z_{4} \rightarrow \mathbb Z_{4}$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I'm interested in how to find it, not the answer itself. I'm confuse to solve this question, I know isomorphism is bijective, and in this case it called Automorphism. But, I can't find a way how to find the answer.

Comment: Look where element $1$ goes. Note, that its image determines the map. For $\pi$ to be isomorphism what conditions on $\pi (1)$ can you give?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $\mathbb{Z}_4$ is cyclic group, so the number of automorphisms can be found using the euler-totient function:
$$\varphi(4)=2$$
Thus there are 2 automorphisms of $\mathbb{Z}_4$. The isomorphisms are:
$$\theta(1)=1$$
$$\theta(1)=3$$

Comment: Are you using $\varphi$ to denote the Euler totient function and an automorphism of $\mathbb{Z}_4$?

Comment: Hi Kuai, now I'm trying to find euler which you mentioned before, and my teacher and in his guide book didn't have euler-totient. Ok, and if Z4 is cylic group, then its generator is 1, isn't it? Just to make sure :

1 = 1
2 = 1 + 1
3 = 1 + 1 + 1
0 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

Right ?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: I just changed the second and third $\varphi$ to $\theta$. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: What you're talking about with Michael, Kuai ? I don't get it.

Comment: @Yagami: Before I was using $\varphi$ to denote both the euler totient function and the bijections, which can be confusing. Now I use $\theta$ to stand for the bijections.

Comment: @Yagami: Euler totient function is counting the number of integers less than $n$ and are relatively prime with $n$. For example, $\varphi(4)=2$ since $1$ and $3$ are coprime with 4; $\varphi(6)=2$ since $1$ and $5$ are coprime with 6.

Comment: Ok, then if the matter is to find how many isomorphism, we just use the euler totient function? And what the condition for this euler's function? In this case why it can be used for finding isomorphism?

Comment: Since all $\mathbb{Z}_n$ groups are cyclic, the isomorphisms are totally determined by where a generator is mapped to. A sufficient condition for a map being an isomorphism is that a generator needs to mapped to a generator, but the generators of a $Z_n$ group are the ones relatively prime with $n$.

Comment: May I ask again ?
So if the question is Z10 --> Z10, using the euler we got $\phi$(10) = 4, the isomorphism are :
$\phi$(1) = 1
$\phi$(1) = 3
$\phi$(1) = 7
$\phi$(1) = 9
Correct?

Comment: @Yagami: correct.

Answer (score 1):

Notice that an automorphism $f$ is entirely determined by $f(1)$ which's a generator of $\mathbb Z_4$ so we have two possibilities:

- $f(1)=1$ and in this case $f=\operatorname{id}$
- $f(1)=3=-1$ and in this case $f=-\operatorname{id}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\mathbb Z_4$ is cyclic with generator $1$ or $3$, every homomorphism $\varphi$ from $\mathbb Z_4$ is completely determined by $\varphi(1)$ or $\varphi(3)$. Let's pick $1$ to work on.

If $\varphi(1) = 0$, then $\varphi$ is the zero map, hence not an automorphism.

If $\varphi(1) = 1$, we have an identity map, which is obviously an automorphism.

If $\varphi(1) = 2$, then $\varphi(2) = \varphi(1) + \varphi(1) = 2 + 2 = 0 = \varphi(0)$. This map is not surjective, hence not an automorphism.

If $\varphi(1) = 3$, then $\varphi(2) = 3 + 3 = 2$ and $\varphi(3) = 3 + 3 + 3 = 1$. This is also an automorphism.

We have two automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Any group homomorphism $\pi:\mathbb Z_4\to G$ is determined by the image of $1$, since $\mathbb Z_4$ is a cyclic group generated by 1, so $\pi(k)=\pi(1+\dots+1)=\pi(1)+\dots+\pi(1)$. Since isomorphisms preserve order, the generator $1$ (of order 4) has to be mapped to another element of order 4. The only elements of order 4 in $\mathbb Z_4$ are $1$ and $3$, so those are the only valid choices to obtain an isomorphism. Choose $1$ and you get the identity automorphism, choose $3$ and you get the automorphism $k\mapsto -k$.